# Function passed as parameter causes an E2035 error

Tags: delphi

In one file, I have a piece of code that goes like this:

```
// foo.pas
unit Foo;

type
FooExecutorMethod = function (param: Pointer) : Integer of Object;

FooExecutor = class
private
  FMethod: TiTefExecutorMethod;
  FMethodParam: Pointer;
  FMethodResult: Integer;
public
  function RunMethod(method: TiTefExecutorMethod; param: Pointer) : Integer;
end;

implementation

function FooExecutor.RunMethod(method: FooExecutorMethod; param: Pointer) : Integer;
begin
  FMethod:= method; // Never gets assigned :(
  FMethodParam:= param;

  // Some threading logic here.  
end;
```

In another file in the same project, I got something like this:

```
// bar.pas
uses Foo;

type
bar = class
protected
  executor: FooExecutor;
  function doSomething(params: Pointer): Integer;
  Constructor Create(params: Pointer);

implementation

Function bar.doSomething(params: Pointer) : Integer;
begin
    // Do something with the pointer
    Result := 1;
end;

Constructor bar.Create(params: Pointer)
var
  r: Integer;
begin
  executor := FooExecutor.Create
  r := executor.RunMethod(doSomething, params);
end;
```

Problem is, `bar.DoSomething` never gets executed. While debugging `FooExecutor.RunMethod`, the evaluator does not show a value for its "`method`" parameter - it shows the following instead:

> E2035 Not enough actual parameters

And thus I am unable to use a reference to `bar.DoSomething`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You do not show your declaration for TiTefExecutorMethod. Is this just a typo that should read FooExecutorMethod? The error E2035 is probably nothing to worry about - it is just the expression evaluator trying to execute the function, which of course it cannot do. And, as David Heffernan comments, in RunMethod you just store the parameters. You don't actually do anything with them.

Answer (score 0):

The method is never executed because you never call it. All you ever do is pass around a reference to the method. But you never call it.

You would call it like this:

```
function FooExecutor.RunMethod(method: FooExecutorMethod; param: Pointer): Integer;
begin
  Result := method(param);
end;
```

Obviously your code is trying to do something else, but this is how to call the method.